# Meaning of 文す, かわらせなく in sorobun, Tanizaki, Yoshino-kuzu

Tags: translation

Ther following is an extract from a letter that the writer quotes in the above book. The letter was found amongst his grand-mother's belongings after she died, apparently a letter sent to her, by her parents, not long after she had married (it seems).

Two items puzzle me. I think 文す should mean 'write a letter' but I can find no such verb anywhere. Also, かわらせなく seems to be used like 変わりなく but that doesn't seem to make sense here.

此度[其身]{そのみ}の孝心をかんしん致{いたし}候ゆえ文して申遣{もうしつかわ}し参らせ候{そろ}左候{さそうら}えば日にまし寒さに向い候え共{ども}いよいよかわらせなく相くらされこのかたも安心いたし居{おり}候ととさんと申{もうし}かかさんと申誠に誠に難有{ありがたく}………

Answer (score 2):

## 英語

To break them down into the parts of speech:

1. 文して:
   「[文]{ふみ}」 -- noun "letter"
   「し」 -- verb 「す」 "to do"
   「て」 -- conjunctive particle
   文して means 文をして, "write a letter" or "inform by a letter."
   Example: 「[文]{ふみ}して告げたれば、返り言、いとあららかにてあり」
   "When I informed him by a letter, his reply was quite blunt." (from 『蜻蛉日記』)
2. かわらせなく:
   「かわら」 -- verb 「かわる」 "to change"
   「せ」 -- honorific auxiliary 「す」 (See: [助動詞「す」 on 古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99))
   「なく」 -- auxiliary 「なし」
   かわらせなく[相]{あい}くらされ means お変わりなく暮らしていらっしゃって "you're living without changing", "you're doing well as before." (相 is a prefix)

---

> The letter was found amongst his grand-mother's belongings after she died, apparently a letter sent to her, by her parents, not long after she had married (it seems).

This letter was written by the grandmother of the author's friend, 津村, addressed to her daughter (=津村's mother). (The sender is ～～左衛門内. 内 means "written by the wife".) When 津村's mother received this letter, she was unmarried and working at the 粉川 household where she had been sold to. Later, she temporarily was atopted into the 浦門 household before getting married into the 津村 family. 津村's parents passed away early, and 津村's grandmother kept this letter.

## 日本語

品詞分解してみますと、

1. 文して：
   「文」 -- 名詞「[文]{ふみ}」
   「し」 -- 動詞「す」
   「て」 -- 接続助詞
   「文して」は「[文]{ふみ}をして」「手紙を書いて」の意。
   例）「[文]{ふみ}して告げたれば、返り言、いとあららかにてあり」
   訳：手紙で知らせると、返事は、とても大ざっぱであった。（出典：『蜻蛉日記』）
2. かわらせなく：
   「かわら」 -- 動詞「かわる」
   「せ」 -- [尊敬の助動詞「す」](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99)
   「なく」 -- 補助形容詞「なし」
   「かわらせなく[相]{あい}くらされ」は「お変わりなく暮らしていらっしゃって」の意（「相」は語調を整える接頭辞）。

---

> The letter was found amongst his grand-mother's belongings after she died, apparently a letter sent to her, by her parents, not long after she had married (it seems).

この手紙は、著者の友人の津村の祖母が、娘（=津村の母）に宛てて書いたものです。（差出人は「～～左衛門内」とあり、「内」は妻が書いたという意味です。）この手紙を受け取った時、津村の母は結婚前で、身売りされた粉川という家で働いていました。この後、一時的に浦門という家に養女に入ってから、津村家にお嫁に行きました。津村の父母は早くに亡くなって、津村の祖母がこの手紙を持っていました。

Comment: 古語辞典の動詞の「す」に、`「愛す」「対面す」「恋す」などのように、体言や体言に準ずる語の下に付いて、複合動詞を作る。` って書いてありますけど関係ありますかね？？

Comment: やはり思ったようでしたか。まったくかわらせなくのせの敬意を表す機能を見逃して、ありがとうございます。

Comment: 書いた人の意図した意味は「尊敬」だと思うんです。でも、普通は「変わら**れ**なく」か「お変わりなく」になると思いますし、「変わらせなく」と尊敬の「せ」を単独で（「せ給う」とせず）使うことってないと思いますから、もしかしたら使い方を間違っているか、少なくとも珍しい使い方してるんじゃないかな～という気がしますよね。。

Comment: 必ずしも尊敬を表す使役のす・さすは「給う」を伴うとは限らないらしいです。小田勝の古典文法総覧にはこの例が載っています：

軒端の梅のほほえめるに鶯のほのかなるは、［松陰中納言ハ］都にても見なれさせけるにや、波路の末の眺めこそ、こよなうめづらしと思す。

ですから、最初におっしゃったとおり、この候文では尊敬のさでしょう。